# minimal length of a closed walk visiting all nodes in directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a strongly connected directed graph G with n nodes and m edges. What is the minimum length of a walk visiting all nodes if the graph is directed?

If the graph is undirected, We need a walk of length at most 2(n-1) (build a spanning tree and then prove it by induction).

The problem is probably very well-known and has its own name, but I was not able to find it.